# Tabular envionment in ConTeXt

Tags: context

guys is there any way to setup a tabular environment in ConteXt. What i need is the equivalent of \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular} (latex command) but in ConTeXt. The goal is to use opentype features like tabular, proportional numbers only in tables.
More info here: [tabular numbers in tables, proportional in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99640/tabular-numbers-in-tables-proportional-in-text)

Comment: More than one: [Table environment](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Tables_Overview). In my opinion, the easiest to use is Natural Tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete example showing how to having old style numbers in the running text and proportional numbers in tables:

```
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
\definefontfeature[lnum][onum=no, lnum=yes]

\setupbodyfont[modern]

\starttext
12345

\startTABLE[style=\addff{lnum}]
  \NC 12345 \NC 67890 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aditya, but what if i use \starttabulate instead \startTABLE?