# Periodic decimal divisions of rational numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, decorations

I would like to code my own Lua(LaTeX) code to obtain periodic decimal divisions like the one below. I know the `xlop` package, but I want another formatting.

[image]

**My question is just about formatting and the missing decorations in my MWE.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% -------------- %
% -- 10 by 11 -- %
% -------------- %

\begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
    1 & 0 &   & & 1 & 1
    \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & & \kern2pt0, & 9 & 0
    \\
         && 1 
    \\
         && 1 & 0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output obtained.

[image]

Comment: I don't know about Lua and `xlop` but it looks like you need `tikzmark` to draw a rectangle around two cells of a `tabular` (possibly on the `background` or before the `tabular` is typeset)  and then just an arc between those two nodes? You could also do it all in TikZ with a `\matrix` of nodes or just some well-placed nodes …

Comment: I just need some help about the formatting (Lua is easy to code). If you have one solution with `TikZ` matrix, it is ok for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea.

The first column of the TikZ-matrix is the left side,
the second column is the right side of your diagram.

I'm using the width of a space which is accessible in PGFmath with `width(" ")` in multiple places:

1. as the `column sep`,
2. as the `inner xsep` and
3. most importantly in the `s` style.

This way, we can say `s=2` and it will shift the node about two digits to the right. With the default value of `1`, you can also simply say `s, s` to shift it about two digits.

Similarly to the second column, you could also insert fake `\0` to pad the left side of a node.

The `anchor=base west` left-aligns all nodes.

In the second column, I'm using `\hphantom{0}` to pad the right side of the node so that line from the `append after command` is long enough.

You could also do `node family={text width=\tikzmatrixname, text width align=left}` [with my `ext.node-families` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121054/16595).

Or you draw these lines after the matrix has been constructed and use the right border of the matrix (which fits tightly against the right-most node of the second column, i.e.

```
(m-2-x.north west) |- (m-2-x.south-|m.east)
```

Depending on the dynamic of these diagrams, it could be interesting to employ `tikz-cd` and use `\arrow[uuuu, <half arc>]` instead.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  matrix,
  calc,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 s/.style={xshift=#1*width("0 ")},
 s/.default=1, % shifts one digit to the right
 m/.style={fill=orange!10, draw=orange!50},
]
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  column sep=2*width(" "),
  every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt},
  /utils/exec=\def\,{\rlap{,}}%    % overwriting \, doesn't seem like a good idea
              \def\0{\hphantom{0}},% but it is local to the \matrix
  nodes={
    anchor=base west, % left-aligned
    inner xsep=.5*width(" ")
  },
  column 2/.append style={
    nodes={
      text depth=+0pt,% comma doesn't contribute to the node size,
                      % alternatively: \def\,{\smash{\rlap{,}}}
      outer sep=+0pt, % anchors on the actual border, just to be safe
      append after command={% draw west and south border of node
                            % overlay so that it doesn't contribute
                            % to the cell's size
        (\tikzlastnode.north west) edge[
          overlay, to path={|-(\tikzlastnode.south east)}]()}
    }
  },
] (m) {
 |[m]| 1 0     & 1   1 \0 \\
       1 0 0   & 0\, 9 0  \\
 |[s, s ]| 1   \\
 |[m,s=2]| 1 0 \\
};
\draw[m, fill=none]
  let \p{angle}=($(m-4-1.south)-(m-1-1.west)$) in
  (m-4-1.south) arc[% half arc between m-4-1.south and m-1-1.west
                  start angle={atan2(\y{angle},\x{angle})},
                  delta angle=-180,
                  radius=.5*veclen(\p{angle})];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very pretty. Thanks for this !

Comment: @projetmbc No problem. This obviously exploits the fact that the digits have all the same width. So choose a font with [tabular digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99640/16595) (and at least activate them for the TikZ node → keys `font` and `node font`).